# wso2 emm use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: http, https, wso2

I would like to know how can I configure wso2 on windows using HTTPS to use HTTP, so my Android Agent wont ask me for a certificate. this is just for testing purposes

Comment: did u find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

By default WSO2 EMM uses http to communicate with it's android agent. As stated in [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Android+Configurations)

> By default, the Android agent communicates with the server through
>   http. For production, this needs to be changed to https, by
>   configuring the following parameters in the Java class named
>   CommonUtilities.java, which is in the org.wso2.emm.agent.utils
>   package: SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT and SERVER_PROTOCOL.

Therefore there shouldn't be an issue in testing your android agent without a certificate.